# Why does dojo.number.format return different results in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, dojo, floating-point, rounding

The following code

```
dojo.number.format(500.005, {places:2})
```

returns 500.01 in Internet Explorer 8 and returns 500.00 in Firefox.

What is the reason for this difference? What did dojo.number.format do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dojo.number.round` has the following comment in its documentation:

> NOTE: Subject to floating point errors.  See dojox.math.round for experimental workaround.